# Failed to get Event Hub description when hitting via POSTMAN

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have created an Event Hub in Azure.

I am trying to gets an Event Hubs description for the specified Event Hub, by following the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/get.

When I am hitting the below URL via POSTMAN by replacing the values as specified in docs:

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroup/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/{namespaceName}/eventhubs/{eventHubName}?api-version=2017-04-01

But I am getting the following error: -

```
    {  
    "error": {  
        "code": "AuthenticationFailed",  
        "message": "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."  
    }  
}
```

Any idea how to get the description about event hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you missed the `Bearer` token in your request, try to `GET` the URL below with your `Bearer` token in the `Authorization`.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/<yourEventhubName>?api-version=2015-08-01
```

Besides, I get my `Bearer` token via powershell and fiddler, you could refer to the steps.

1.Run the powershell below.

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName >-ResourceType Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces -ResourceName "<yourEventHubName>" -ApiVersion 2015-08-01
```

2.Use fiddler to catch the request, it will send two requests, choose any one, just copy the token.

[image]

In the Postman, send the `GET` with the `Bearer` token, it works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: @RudraSingh Did you install [Azure RM powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.5.0)? If not, I think you could install it first.

Comment: @RudraSingh AFAIK, there is no permanent key for request, the access token just could be refreshed, you could learn more about `token` from the two articles, [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims).

Comment: @RudraSingh Also, here is another way for you to use this api, just use `Try it` in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/get).